# In Christ's time the Jews believed in Purgatory and still do. Why don't Protestants?

Tags: purgatory

The Jews believe in Purgatory, why don't Protestants?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Jews believed in Purgatory in the way that Catholics do. Protestants reject it because they find no scriptural warrant for it (although they may have some sympathy for Jewish beliefs).

Comment: Jewish Encyclopedia: "The view of purgatory is still more clearly expressed in rabbinical passages, as in the teaching of the Shammaites: "In the last judgment day there shall be three classes of souls: the righteous shall at once be written down for the life everlasting; the wicked, for Gehenna; but those whose virtues and sins counterbalance one another shall go down to Gehenna and float up and down until they rise purified; ...

Comment: ... for of them it is said: 'I will bring the third part into the fire and refine them as silver is refined, and try them as gold is tried' [Zech. xiii. 9.]; also, 'He [the Lord] bringeth down to Sheol and bringeth up again'" (I Sam. ii. 6). The Hillelites seem to have had no purgatory ... they also speak of an intermediate state."

Comment: Not all protestant denominations disbelieve in an intermediate state between this life and heaven.  They just don't agree with the Roman Catholic description of it. Lutherans, Methodists, Episcopleans, and Orthodox (Yes - not Protestant per se) pray for the dead, which attest to the existence of this intermediate state.

Comment: I would add some reference two jewish beliefs.  You could start with the prayer for the dead, which in itself does not point to Purgatory perfectly, but when combined with the jewish traditions, points towards how the supplications are heard by god on behalf of the deceased.

Answer (score 2):

What Purgatory is; providing that the general impression among Protestants is correct; is a place where the dead await becoming sinless, and when that happens they are then admitted to Heaven. The fact that such a place existed until Jesus suffered on the Cross; appears to be proven by the following Scripture.

> Matthew 27:52-53 And the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose, And came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many.

Then when Jesus resurrected all those awaiting Heaven, were loosed from there, and proceeded to enter Heaven. Those beliefs are based on Several passages from the Bible. They are:

> Job 14:12-15 So man lieth down, and riseth not: till the heavens [be] no more, they shall not awake, nor be raised out of their sleep. O that thou wouldest hide me in the grave, that thou wouldest keep me secret, until thy wrath be past, that thou wouldest appoint me a set time, and remember me! If a man die, shall he live [again]? all the days of my appointed time will I wait, till my change come. Thou shalt call, and I will answer thee: thou wilt have a desire to the work of thine hands.
>
> Job 19:25-27 For I know [that] my redeemer liveth, and [that] he shall stand at the latter [day] upon the earth: And [though] after my skin [worms] destroy this [body], yet in my flesh shall I see God:  Whom I shall see for myself, and mine eyes shall behold, and not another; [though] my reins be consumed within me.
>
> Daniel 12:2-3 And many of them that sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, some to everlasting life, and some to shame [and] everlasting contempt. And they that be wise shall shine as the brightness of the firmament; and they that turn many to righteousness as the stars for ever and ever.
>
> Hosea 13:14 I will ransom them from the power of the grave; I will redeem them from death: O death, I will be thy plagues; O grave, I will be thy destruction: repentance shall be hid from mine eyes.

All of there are prophesies from the Old testament, which precedes Salvation.

From the New Testament the following Scriptures appear to indicate that that place no longer exists:

> Matthew 28:6-7 He is not here: for he is risen, as he said. Come, see the place where the Lord lay. And go quickly, and tell his disciples that he is risen from the dead; and, behold, he goeth before you into Galilee; there shall ye see him: lo, I have told you.

Jesus apparently negated the need for a place of atonement when he sacrificed his life on the cross.

Since the man Jesus took on all the sins of those who put their eternal faith in him, He also must be loosed from whatever interment he underwent for the three days he was in the Grave. That alone shows that all sins of those who are destined for Heaven are forgiven.

The following Scripture tells us that at his sacrifice people who are in their graves will come forth to judgment.

> John 5:28-29 Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which all that are in the graves shall hear his voice, And shall come forth; they that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and they that have done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation.

Matthew 27:52-53 would appear to indicate that the hearing of his call has already transpired. The part about resurrection of life, and resurrection to damnation, obviously will not happen until the great white throne judgment of the Revelation.

The following Scripture appears to tell us that at some time in the future Jesus will issue another call and that the elect will not be in any waiting place, but will be scattered throughout Heaven.

> Matthew 24:31 And he shall send his angels with a great sound of a trumpet, and they shall gather together his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other.

The following promise of Jesus to the thief tells us that he will not go to a waiting place, but will go to Heaven to be with Jesus.

> Luke 23:42 and 43  And he said unto Jesus, Lord, remember me when thou comest into thy kingdom. And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, To day shalt thou be with me in paradise.

Comment: FYI - Purgatory is not a place where you wait to become sinless.  It is a place of final sanctification.  What ever your faith background, most denominations wether subjective or not believe that at the time of ours death,  we through the grace of our lord Jesus Christ will be made perfect (by some means)  that is the believer's (really don't like the word) final sanctification.  This final sanctification is what the Catholic Church refers to as Purgatory.  The details of this sanctification are a mystery, but we do know that this must occur, wether in an instant or over a period of time.

Comment: @Marc FYI  I have no quarrel with the Catholic belief system. There is no reason to believe that any system of belief, is more acceptable to God than another. Jesus; who obviously knew the future of the Church he started, only said that those who put their trust in him, would escape eternal damnation. I have no reason to believe that any Denomination does not qualify under those requirements. My answer was and is meant to give what appears to be the Protestant conviction as to why we reserve the right to believe that a place of sanctification whether temporary or instantaneous still exists.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you have a quarrel.  Is there a Protestant sect that believes Purgatory is a state where you go to become sinless?  I'm not concerned with a person creating their own subjective belief system, or having some kind of moral relativism where faith and morals match their politics or culture or simply make them feel better of feed there ego.  My comment suggests that there is a problem with the first part of they answer,  "a place where the dead await becoming sinless"  is either an incorrect understanding or a belief system in Christianity that I am unaware of.

Comment: @Marc I found no offense in comment, and only included the statement as a preliminary to my conviction that no Denomination is superior to any other. As far as dead awaiting a sinless condition; it is common belief that Catholics pray for those in Purgatory, and some believe that they can pray another into Heaven. I do not know if such is a fallacious belief or not, only that is common among the Protestants I know. The becoming sinless is my own acronym. Shall we let this be the last exchange on this?

Comment: I would just suggest a better understanding of Purgatory,  as to what you believe, that has nothing to do with OP’s question or your answer.  Any hoot, I’m done